# An integral from Sato's book

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

I am reading Sato's book on Levy Processes and in one of his calculations, there seems to be the following suggestion:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2+1)^{(d+1)/2}} dx = \frac{1}{(a^2+1)^{d/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{(d+1)/2}} dx$$

where $d \in \{1,2,3,4...\}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

I can't prove this...

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $x = (a^2 + 1)^{1/2}u$, we have

$$\int_{\Bbb R} \frac{1}{(x^2 + a^2 + 1)^{(d + 1)/2}}\, dx = \int_{\Bbb R} \frac{1}{(a^2 + 1)^{(d + 1)/2}(u^2 + 1)^{(d + 1)/2}} (a^2 + 1)^{1/2}\, du, $$

and the last integral simplifies to

$$\frac{1}{(a^2 + 1)^{d/2}}\int_{\Bbb R} \frac{1}{(u^2 + 1)^{d/2}}\, du.$$

Comment: ahhhhh I had just figured this out myself, but thanks a lot nonetheless!!!